# Turn 2D Logo into 3D using css?

Tags: css, 3d

what I want to achieve: I want to make a rotating 3D Logo out of a 2d png.

For rotating, ofcourse, I will  use the 3D transform from CSS3. But is there some CSS which can give a png some depth? Like in Illustrator using extrusion? I have seen you can do things like a 3d cube in CSS3. But the Logo has many curves and I really don't know where to start to achieve this effect.

Are there any resources where I could look that up? Yet I didn't find anyhting.

Best regards

Comment: I would use an animated gif for this. CSS won't allow you to "extrude" a shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built a CSS 3D engine which can load obj files. So you have to build your logo in a 3D program and export it as obj file.

Example: http://css3d.bitworking.de/examples/example05.html

It has some drawbacks: You can only use planar quad elements to model the object. And it's not very fast. (My logo has 276 div elements and it's very CPU intensive)

So if the logo don't have to be interactive you'd better use a gif animation, movie or sprite animation (interactive to some extent).

Else you can use WebGL (for example the JS library http://threejs.org/) which is hardware accelerated and can handle much polygons well. But you also have to build the logo in a 3D program which can export to obj, 3ds, fbx, ctm or blend file format. (For example http://www.blender.org/)

Examples:

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_stl

Answer (score 0):

There's the "new" css `drop-shadow()` filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#drop-shadow()

But there isn't currently a CSS way to "extrude" 2d shapes into 3d. Your best bet is to make a .png that already has this, if only for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Ah I see.. Thanks for the response. I guess we have to wait some time until that can happen